# debian error installing package php5-tidy

Tags: linux, debian-wheezy, php5

have an issue with php5-tidy.

Looks something broke and I am not able to figure out. Have tried all options of --purge and so on to clean and re-install but to no avail.

Following is the error I am getting for apt-get install php5-tidy:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libtidy-0.99-0
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libtidy-0.99-0
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 74 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/155 kB of archives.
After this operation, 433 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 23110 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libtidy-0.99-0 (from .../libtidy-0.99-0_20091223cvs-1.2+deb7u1_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libtidy-0.99-0_20091223cvs-1.2+deb7u1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/libtidy.so', which is also in package tidy 5.2.0
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libtidy-0.99-0_20091223cvs-1.2+deb7u1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Appreciate any help and thanks :)

Comment: Is the cvs version you are attempting to install in the same environment as the 5.2 packaged version that is conflicting?  If so look at the documentation or  configure switches and maybe consider a --prefix=/usr/local | /opt  to allow for segregation ( this assumes you need both, if not consider retrying apt-get purge libtidy again sharing any errors that provides here (if any) if successful retry the cvs version install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hunting around came up with this command:

```
apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" install libtidy-0.99-0
```

got some pointers and help from this discussion: https://askubuntu.com/a/491086

Result was a force to install (or re-install) libtidy-0.99-0